# C Program - How to validate a specific string in a file

Tags: c

Please bear with me I'm still new to C programming, my goal is to get a serial number that is saved in a file called `mtd0` and validate that serial number. In bash, the command is:

```
dd if=/dev/mtd0 bs=1 skip=$((0x1fc30)) count=16 2>/dev/null
```

And the output should be:

```
1866203214226041
```

But I want to do it in pure C language, what I have tried so far is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *s;

    fp = fopen("/tmp/mtd0","rb");
    if(NULL == fp) {
        printf("\n Cannot open file!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    typedef unsigned char byte; 
    byte s_no[16];
    fseek(fp, 0x1fc30, SEEK_SET);
    fread(s_no, 1, 16, fp);
    printf ("Serial number: %s\n", s_no);
    fclose(fp);

    char mtd0[16];
    char defser[16];
    int ret;

    memcpy(mtd0, s_no, 16);
    memcpy(defser, "1866203214226041", 16);

    ret = memcmp(mtd0, defser, 16);

    if(ret == 0)
    {
        printf("Serial number is correct!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Serial number is not correct\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

But when I execute that, it doesn't print anything.
`mtd0` is not an ordinary text file, I don't know what it's called but the file looks like [this](http://www.filedropper.com/mtd0) please download that file if you need more info. So how can I fix my code above ?

Comment: That is called a *binary file*.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you, but do you know how to fix my code above ?

Comment: in C you'll need to use `strcmp` not `==` to compare strings and `fread` to read the data from the file.

Comment: `sn = fread( fp, 0x1fc30, 16 );
    printf ("Serial number: %s\n", sn );` --> `fread()` returns `size_t`, some integer type.  That is not something to print with `printf ("%s", sn );`  Certainly your compiler should provide a warning.  Enable all warnings to save time.

Comment: Keep in mind that the string `1866203214226041` will be inserted verbatim into the resulting binary, thus making cracking the protection trivial.

Comment: Watch the program in your debugger, and see why you're not getting any output at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with what you're doing.

1. `fseek` simply adjusts the file pointer for the *next* read or write from the file; it doesn't actually retrieve anything from the file for you.  Furthermore, the valid values for the third argument to `fseek` are:

   - `SEEK_SET` -  set the position of the file pointer to the beginning of the file plus the value in the second argument
   - `SEEK_CUR` -  set the position of the file pointer to the current position of the file pointer, plus the value in the second argument
   - `SEEK_END` -  set the position of the file pointer to the end of the file.
2. Assuming you meant to do "read 16 bytes from the file at position 0x1fc30", you would want to save that data as a byte array, not a string:

   ```
   typedef unsigned char byte; 
   byte s_no[16];
   fseek(fp, 0x1fc30, SEEK_SET);
   fread(s_no, 1, 16, fp);
   ```
3. While `strcmp` is the correct way to compare strings in C, if the serial number is stored as *bytes*, which I'm assuming it is, because `/dev/mtd0` looks like a binary file, you would have to compare memory using `memcmp` with another byte array set to the valid value for the serial.

Comment: Hi, thank you I've managed to compare the serial number but there's a little problem with my code, sometimes the serial number displays additional characters in the end like this https://s27.postimg.org/dkumqgmcj/screenshot_2017_01_17_01_34_16.png I have updated my code in my post, please take a look at it again

Comment: @hillz If you are printing it out as a string, make the byte array 17 elements long and manually set the last element (`s_no[16]`) to be 0 before calling `printf` but after calling `fread`

Answer (score 0):

fseek does not read from the file, it just moves the file pointer around for your next read. You need to use fread to read from the file. Documentation on fread can be found here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread.

Additionally, it is good practice to open a binary file in binary mode:

```
fopen("mtd0","rb");
```

As per Alden's comment, string comparison in C is done using a function called strcmp, whose documentation can be found here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp.

Finally, you should probably fully qualify the path to mtd0, i.e.:

```
fopen("/dev/mtd0","rb");
```

Comment: It still doesn't print anything, can you please download the mtd0 file that I have provided above and see what's wrong with my code? I have also updated my code above with your suggestion

Comment: Fread doesn't return its output, it returns the number of items it has read. Take another look at the documentation on fread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strcmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm):

```
if (strcmp (sn, "1866203214226041") != 0) {
    printf("Serial number is correct\n");
}
```